# How to relate two variables in JSON POST request

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests

I have a JMeter test scenario as follows: several hundred users have to login to a platform and send a POST request with several hundred of profiles to generate a report. For the data, I use two csv files.

One csv file contains the data of the users with which JMeter will login and send a POST request to generate a report. It contains the following fields:

```
userid,  companyid, password
```

once logged in, each of these users has to choose profiles from another csv file, to generate reports about those profiles. The other csv file has these fields:

```
profileid, companyid
```

Each user can only generate profiles of the profiles that have the same companyid.

The profiles have to be placed inside an array, which in turn is inside an object, in a JSON request.  IMPORTANT: all the profiles have to be placed inside the array in a single iteration. That means that if there are 1000 profiles, they have to be set on the array at the same time.

I haven't been able to:

1. Figure out how to ensure that for each user, the specific profiles available to that user get set in the array.
2. Figure out how to actually insert the values in the array, all in a single iteration .

Could someone offer advice on how to achieve this?

Disclaimer: I don't know Java and I have just begun using JMeter a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1
You can use a [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) element to read the data, `userid,  companyid, password` from the first CSV file.
Add a CSV Data Set Config element to read the user credentials.

[image]

It will read one row for each thread and each iteration.

Now you have the companyid available for the entire iteration. You need to filter the data with the companyid from the second CSV file. This can be done with Groovy (you can use Java too).

Add a JSR223 Sampler to retrieve the `profileid` from the second CSV file. Following code demonstrates reading the CSV file into list of files and then filter the lines with `companyid`

```
log.info("Processing profile")

def lines = new File('company_profiles.csv').readLines()
def filteredLine=lines.find { it.contains(args[0])}
def lstRecord = filteredLines.get(currentRecord).split(",")
vars.put("profileid","${lstRecord[0]}")

SampleResult.setIgnore()
```

NOTE : `companyid` is passed to the script as an argument. Please see the highlighted areas in the following.

[image]

The `profileid` is set as a variable in the script `vars.put("profileid","${lstRecord[0]}")`. You can use the profileid within the iteration of the current thread with `${profileid}`

Comment: Janesh, thank you for your answer! I greatly appreciate the time you took for your answer :) However,  I don't know how to implement your answer. Could you give me a slow walk-thorough of the process? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to provide a comprehensive answer without seeing your CSV files structure so I can provide only a generic piece of advice:

If you're looking at [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) be aware that it reads the next line on each iteration, if you need to read multiple lines within the bounds of a single iteration you need to use [__CSVRead() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime) or consider using [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) for scripting

Comment: Hi Dimitri, thanks for your reply: I have reformulated my question, and hopefully stated myproblem with more clarity. This is the link to the new question, in case you want to take a look at it. Thanks a lot!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69890436/how-to-insert-several-values-into-an-array-in-a-post-request-in-jmeter