# How to insert several values into an array in a POST Request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am having some serious difficulties with the following. I have am HTTP sampler to send a POST request. The post request is a JSON object and the first property is an array. The array saves options chosen by a user, so, for example, if the user chooses 3 options, then the 3 ids of those options will be inserted into the array, all at once (no iterations, its a single request.

The part of the object of interest looks like this (I've made up those numbers):

```
{"Ids":[311, 312, 313], ......}
```

I had to use __CSVRead inside the array, because the apps functionality is a tad complex, and I need to make sure that the user that makes the choices actually chooses options that are exclusively available to that particular user. After some research, I managed to to this:

```
{"Ids":[${__CSVRead(${companyId}.csv,0)}${__CSVRead(${companyId}.csv,next)}], ......}
```

And this worked well, except for the fact that only the first row of the csv file gets inserted.

The csv files I'm using have a single row(no headers), like such (again, made up numbers:

```
311
312
313
```

So I saved the file like this to get everything in the same line:

```
"311,312,313"
```

And it didn't work, the data got sent like this:

```
{"Ids":["3011], ......}
```

And I got the following error in the response:

```
{"Ids[0]":["Error converting value \"3011],\" to type 'System.Int64'. Path 'Ids[0]', line 1, position 32.","After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: c. Path 'Ids[0]', line 1, position 32.","After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: c. Path 'Ids[0]', line 1, position 32."],"Ids[0].Ids":["Infinite loop detected from error handling. Path 'Ids[0]', line 1, position 32."]}
```

I've also tried other variations, such as

```
"3011,""3012,""3013"
```

But the request gets sent the same way and I get the same response error.

Could someone please offer some advice on what i'm doing wrong?

I've been stuck on this for days.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to send an array of Integers not Strings. In long run you could create a simple POJO to create a JSON payload. You can call setter method to set the IDs.  I will provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(new groovy.json.JsonBuilder([Ids: new File(vars.get('companyId') + '.csv').readLines().collect()]).toPrettyString(),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks Dimitri!! I do have a question, however. The code you sent creates an entire object, but i just need to populate the array. How could I modify your code so that it is inside the array, which in turn is already inside an object? Ids is just one of many other properties inside that object. Thanks a lot!

I tried the following, but it didn't work:
{"Ids":[${__groovy(new File(vars.get('companyId') + '.csv').readLines().collect()).toPrettyString(),))}] .......rest of object}

Answer (score -1):

Following approach is suitable in long run where you can manipulate the JSONObject easily and generate the required payload.

You can convert a sample JSON payload into a JAVA objects with online tools or using a [plugin in IDE](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8533-json2pojo)s.

Add a [JSR223 Preprocessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) to your HTTP Request as a child element.
Include following into the script section.

```
import groovy.json.JsonGenerator
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

//This class will have to include all the fields
//Convert a sample JSON to generate this class 
//Remove the methods as setters/getters are automatically created by Groovy
//This class can be included in a JAR file and imported to the script.

class JSONPayload {

   Integer[] ids

}

def lstIDs = [123,234,123] //You need to set a list of IDs 

JSONPayload jsonObject = new JSONPayload()
jsonObject.setIds(lstIDs)

def generator = new JsonGenerator.Options()
    .excludeNulls()
    .build()

def jsonRequest = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(generator.toJson(jsonObject))
vars.put("jsonRequest",jsonRequest)
```

Above script will create the required JSON payload and set into the JMeter variable `jsonRequest`

[Parsing and Generating JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html) with Groovy

[image]

Now you can use the variable `${jsonRequest}` in the HTTP Request
Set the payload in the HTTPRequest --> Body
[image]